# Read variable from screen and time from separate file

Tags: bash

I want to read the variable from the screen in stead of typing inside the file. I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
STARTED_TIME=10:46:20
RECORDED_TIME=(
11:03:00
11:24:00
11:27:00
11:32:00
)
SEC1=$(date +%s -d "${STARTED_TIME}")
for d in "${RECORDED_TIME[@]}"
do
  SEC2=$(date +%s -d "$d")
  DIFFSEC=$(( SEC2 - SEC1 ))
  echo "$DIFFSEC"
done
```

The previous one worked fine. Now two things am looking for. First is to read the SATRED_TIME from screen command, and the another one is to read the RECORDED_TIME from another separate file. I would appreciate any help.

```
     #!/bin/bash  
     echo "What is the started time?"
     read time
  STARTED_TIME=$time 
RECORDED_TIME=(
recorded_time.txt
)
SEC1=$(date +%s -d "${STARTED_TIME}")
for d in "${RECORDED_TIME[@]}"
do
  SEC2=$(date +%s -d "$d")
  DIFFSEC=$(( SEC2 - SEC1 ))
  echo "$DIFFSEC"
done

cat Recorded_time.txt
11:03:00 
11:24:00
11:27:00
11:32:00
```

Comment: There are three different spellings of `STARTED_TIME` in your question, which doesn't help making it any more clear. What's `#!/bin/bash echo` supposed to do? What's your expected and actual output?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I copied it without paying attention. It's supposed to work as the first input file which is to subtract the recorded time from the started time and print it in seconds.

Comment: The only two things changed with respect to the first input file is the started time and recorded time. Started time needs to be red from the screen by typing it manually and the recorded time needs to be read from the separate file named as recorded_time.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write something like this:

```
$ cat time.sh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "What is the started time? " started_time
mapfile -t recorded_time < Recorded_time.txt

sec1=$(date +%s -d "${started_time}") || exit 2
for rec_time in "${recorded_time[@]}"; do
    sec2=$(date +%s -d "$rec_time")
    diffsec=$(( sec2 - sec1 ))
    echo "$diffsec"
done
```

Then, you can do

```
$ bash time.sh
What is the started time? 11:00:00
180
1440
1620
1920
```

I'm using `read -p` to specify the prompt for the read command, and the `mapfile` command to read the lines of a file into a shell array.

Also, it's good practice to avoid using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: those should be used by the shell only.